# Website displaying differently on desktop browser vs ipad browser

Tags: ipad

I am currently working on retrofitting a website from the ground up to be ipad friendly. I'm noticing that its size is slightly off compared to the desktop version of the site. I have included photos of the site for comparison.

I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and still nothing.

All sizes are set in pixel width or percentages. The blue sidebar is set in px, the content area to the right is just absolute positioned.

Desktop Screen Cap:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0p4T6XDlqiyVmVnNmNFMDVBV00/edit?usp=sharing

iPad Screen Cap:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0p4T6XDlqiyQmVma291dkctV0E/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is extremely embarrassing but for whatever reason my code wasn't getting passed into the site. After some fiddling with the server and making sure I was in the correct spot it looks like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` worked perfectly.

Strange that there was no issue on the android devices I tested, only on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

So I got to ask if a CSS Library is being used? Similar things have happened to me. The first issue was that my CSS Library (bootstrap 3) was automatically being responsive. The other reason this happened to me was because the iPad had retina display and my desktop did not, however it was not that different. Without knowing what tools you are using to help build the site that is my best guess.

Comment: No CSS library. iPad is retina, desktop is not, however it seems far too drastic for that to be the sole issue.